# Swift / iOS: is there a way to achieve a Peek and Pop effect for a UITableViewCell without using the 3D touch API?

Tags: ios, uitableview, preview

Is there a way to display contextually a preview of a **UITableViewCell**?

This is a sketch of the behaviour that I would like, where "preview" represents a preview window that is displayed on top of the cell, when the cell is selected.

[image]

I can detect the "isSelected" event, but I am unsure which UI element to use to display this smoothly (UIAlertViews don't really seem smooth enough - I want something that can   disappear once the user moves the finger away without the need of an action)

Comment: The thing you are looking for is 3D touch

Comment: Yes but how do you link it with a preview? Is there some API provided by Apple that provides a preview? Also a similar behaviour is achievable not using 3D and only a combination of touch detection (for earlier versions of iPhone).... The function that you are referring to is called "Peek and Pop". Not quiet sure why the "close" vote.

Comment: mm24 I haven't vote to close your question.

Comment: that's cool.. however someone did.. not sure why